# Euler Circuit with least deviation from input

Tags: algorithms, graphs, eulerian-paths

So given an undirected graph stored in form adjacency list using `vector<int> adj[]`, I have to print the Euler Cicuit. Every edge is given as follows `a b`meaning an edge from `a to b`.

But the problem is I have to follow the given order of input of vertices connected by an edge and change the order whenever it is compulsory.

For eg- input:

```
a b
c b
c a
```

Now for the cycle it has to be from `b c`. But if it was

```
a b
b c
c d
d b
b e
e a
```

There are multiple answers but ***I want the answer which deviates least from input***. So the answer will be same as input.

How can I do this ? I found that Hierholzer's algorithm can be used to print the euler circuit. But the order will not be as I want.

Comment: How do you measure *deviation from the input*? Do two successive input edges always have a node in common? If so, then the edges reduce to a path. How do you measure the deviation between this and the output circuit?

Comment: @Thumbnail Yes,two successive input edges always have a node in common.If the given input is indeed an Euler cycle, I should print it as it is but if it's not I may have to change the order of `a  b` to `b a`.